# Can I create new table on SQL without specifying the datatype?

Tags: sql

I want to create new table with empty columns and specify the datatype later. Is it possible? I try to do so on myscompiler.io and it works. I don't know if it's just possible in such site or is it actually possible to create that once I use other tools to write my SQL.

Comment: no, at least Table has to have one column with datatype

Comment: No, the column will give error if defined as plain null.

Comment: @nimaansari All columns must be with datatype, running this `create table test5 (Age int, address)` gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The SQL syntax requires that a table be well-defined, with column names and data types.  This is true in every database that I can think of.

You could *possibly* do what you want in one of three ways:

- Your database might support some sort of generic type which you could use to define the column.  For instance, SQL Server has a `sql_variant` type.
- You could define the table with a specific type such as a string and change the type later using `alter table`.
- You could define the table with a single primary key column and add columns as you decide what they are.

**I don't recommend any of these approaches.**  Instead, I would suggest that you need to re-think how your application is structured.  Tables represent *entities* and entities have *properties*.  Generally when using databases, these things are known before you start doing any work.  There may be some cases where dynamic table creation is useful, but that is definitely not the common approach when using databases.

Comment: As a note for the second option, the column (as per table creation) won't cease to exist - it will stay in the table.